# CSS blur effect takes too long the first time

Tags: javascript, css, gsap

There is a page I want to blur using the following function :

```
var mainInfo;
function clonemain() {
    var Main = document.querySelector('#main');
    var Clone = Main.cloneNode(true);
    Clone.style.opacity=0;
    Clone.style.filter="blur(6px)";
    Clone.style.webkitFilter="blur(6px)";
    Clone.style.mozFilter="blur(6px)";
 }       
 document.querySelector('body').appendChild(Clone);
    return [Main,Clone];
}
function blurry(Main,Clone) {
    TweenLite.to(Main,0.25,{opacity:0});
    TweenLite.to(Clone,0.25,{opacity:1});
    Clone.style.display="block";
}
```

It makes a duplicate of a `div`, blurs it out and hides it using `opacity = 0`.

The problem is that it takes a lot of time the first time the opacity changes and the duplication occurs. It works fine the next times the animation loads.
For instance, this issue can be resolved using a sort of "pre processing" on page load, with blurring and then instantly returning it back to normal , but it still takes the same amount of time.

```
blurry(mainInfo[0],mainInfo[1]);
blurry(mainInfo[1],mainInfo[0]);
```

Does someone know why this is happening and how it can be fixed?

**Edit :**

I need to note that even when I close the tab but not the actual browser the next time the page is loaded , the animation works fine .

Comment: It would be useful if you provide a demo of the problem (e.g. using JSFiddle).

Comment: Unfortunately that is not much of an option .
This is a part of a bigger project , if i am going to provide a demo , i need to write it again.

Comment: Demos are extremely helpful, though. As you know, it's hard to say much without seeing the larger context. Sometimes you have to write a test to find a bug.

Comment: That said, blurring is an expensive operation, and it is more expensive the larger the blur radius. Have you tried decreasing the radius to a smaller value and seeing if that improves your loading time?

Comment: Actually its not the radius that is high, its the size and number of the elements that are being blurred. I know why it's lagging I just want know why it doesn't lag the second time and how the lag prevented.

Comment: can you specify the time for each part to load ?
ex :
? ms to load first image
? ms to read images between js code and first image
? ms to create second image
? ms to blur second image

Answer (score 1):

" I know why it's lagging I just want know why it doesn't lag the second time and how the lag prevented."

The reason is web browsers's cache :
A web cache is a mechanism for the temporary storage (caching) of web documents, such as HTML pages and images, to reduce bandwidth usage, server load, and perceived lag.

Source:
[wiki Web_cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_cache)